# Same keras models do not give the same output for get_config() method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I would like to know why for two same keras models, sometimes get_method() gives the same results (See `model_dense_A` and `model_dense_B`) and sometimes not (example for `model_conv_A` and `model_conv_B`).

Even if I use the `clear_session()` method and the exact same code, the models are still different.

Does someone know about this behaviour ?

Code snippet:

```
from tensorflow import keras

input_shape = (300, 3)

# MODEL DENSE A
keras.backend.clear_session()
input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
out = keras.layers.Flatten()(input_)
out = keras.layers.Dense(units=100, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')(out)
mdl_dense_A = keras.models.Model(name='dense', inputs=input_, outputs=out)

# MODEL DENSE B
keras.backend.clear_session()
input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
out = keras.layers.Flatten()(input_)
out = keras.layers.Dense(units=100, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')(out)
mdl_dense_B = keras.models.Model(name='dense', inputs=input_, outputs=out)

print(mdl_dense_A.get_config() == mdl_dense_B.get_config())  # True

# MODEL CONV1D-LSTM A
keras.backend.clear_session()
input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
branch_outputs = []
for i in range(input_shape[-1]):
    out = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.expand_dims(x[:, :, i], axis=-1))(input_)
    out = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='valid')(out)
    branch_outputs.append(out)
out = keras.layers.Concatenate()(branch_outputs)
recursive = keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)(out)
recursive = keras.layers.LSTM(50)(recursive)
out = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(recursive)
mdl_conv_A = keras.models.Model(name='conv1d-lstm', inputs=input_, outputs=out)

# MODEL CONV1D-LSTM B
keras.backend.clear_session()
input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
branch_outputs = []
for i in range(input_shape[-1]):
    out = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.expand_dims(x[:, :, i], axis=-1))(input_)
    out = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='valid')(out)
    branch_outputs.append(out)
out = keras.layers.Concatenate()(branch_outputs)
recursive = keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)(out)
recursive = keras.layers.LSTM(50)(recursive)
out = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(recursive)
mdl_conv_B = keras.models.Model(name='conv1d-lstm', inputs=input_, outputs=out)

print(mdl_conv_A.get_config() == mdl_conv_B.get_config())  # False !?
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually helps to take a look at where exactly both configs differ, i.e.

```
print(mdl_conv_A.get_config() == mdl_conv_B.get_config(), (mdl_conv_A.get_config(), mdl_conv_B.get_config()))  # False !?
```

In this case they differ because of the lambda layer, which is not very serializable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would you advice for comparing these two models ? I am figuring out how to write a unit test for this case.